# On feasibility of indexing blobs on Azure using the Azure Search blob indexer

Tags: json, azure, indexing, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to learn about blob storage. I have two questions regarding [indexing of the blob storage on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs):
Can I create indexer and run it on demand instead of scheduling the indexer?
I have following sample of content stored in a blob:

```
{  
   "Rows":[  
      {  
         "RowId":"20211345-2b71-4258-b4a6-4474284d78b5",
         "Text":"BIO Vegan Frog Bolognese Sauce 6x225gr",
         "Status":2
      },
      {  
         "RowId":"28370d6c-5e58-4dda-b874-97ad25cc1361",
         "Text":"Gezondheid & Dieet",
         "Status":1
      },
      {  
         "RowId":"320254f1-2163-48e0-b549-75e818136b48",
         "Text":"BIO Vegan Frog Houmous Classic 12x95gr",
         "Status":2
      },
      {  
         "RowId":"1dfc7fb9-816c-4f35-82f3-bbf83c3d89da",
         "Text":"Vegan Producten"
         "Status":3
      }
   ],
   "Columns":[  
      "ID",
      "Title",
      "Status"
   ],
   "BlobName":"115a46d0919e4b6bb7051dce1e766e45"
}
```

I would like to create index on the rows status and be able to use the indexer to retrieve a list of rows with a specific status. for example to get the following result for searching for status=2

```
{  
   "Rows":[  
      {  
         "RowId":"20211345-2b71-4258-b4a6-4474284d78b5",
         "Text":"BIO Vegan Frog Bolognese Sauce 6x225gr",
         "Status":2
      },
      {  
         "RowId":"320254f1-2163-48e0-b549-75e818136b48",
         "Text":"BIO Vegan Frog Houmous Classic 12x95gr",
         "Status":2
      }
   ],
   "Columns":[  
      "ID",
      "Title",
      "Status"
   ],
   "BlobName":"115a46d0919e4b6bb7051dce1e766e45"
}
```

What I would like to know is whether this scenario is feasible or not.

Comment: What indexer are you referring to?

Comment: please read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-index-json-blobs

Comment: Rather than me reading about Azure Search, please edit your question to specifically call out that's what you're talking about. You left that detail out of your question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon I added the link to the post as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have other use cases you need to cover off? If they are all JSON based, then consider Cosmos DB instead of Azure Search and Blob storage. You can achieve your result using only one service. Store the JSON in your blob in a document and then you can query over it using the APIs. [Here is a simple example.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-documentdb-dotnet)

Cosmos DB allows you to choose your consistency level for balancing performance and optimising costs.

[From the docs:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels)

- Strong: Linearizability
- Bounded Staleness: Consistent Prefix. Reads lag behind writes by k prefixes or t interval
- Session: Consistent Prefix. Monotonic reads, monotonic writes, read-your-writes, write-follows-reads
- Consistent Prefix: Updates returned are some prefix of all the updates, with no gaps
- Eventual: Out of order read

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to create an indexer on the blob container but if you would want to create and run the indexer on demand for a specific blob for such search scenario you mentioned, you will end up having to opt for a very pricey plan for your Azure Search Service. you can get the pricing details in [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/search/).